# Maximal element of set of submodules not containing an element of a module $M$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, modules

Been having bad time trying to solve the following problem and I would really appreciate some help.

Let $M$ be a (left) $R$-module, $x\in M-\left\{0\right\}$ and $\Lambda=\left\{A\leq M:x\notin A\right\}$.

(a) Prove that $\Lambda$ is non-empty and that it has a maximal element (with respect to the inclusion as ordering).

(b) If $R=K$  is a field, show that every maximal element of $\Lambda$ is a maximal submodule of $M$.

My work so far:

For part a) It is rather obvious that $\Lambda$ is not empty and is a partially ordered set (poset). Then I used Zorn's lemma: Let $\Gamma$ be a chain (a totally ordered subset of $\Lambda$), if $\Gamma=\emptyset$, then every element of $\Lambda$ is an upper bound of $\Gamma$. Otherwise, if $\Gamma=\left\{A_{i}\in \Lambda| i\in I\right\}\neq\emptyset$ where $I$ is some indexing set, let $N=[\sum_{i\in I}A_{i}-Rx)$ (here $[X)$ means the submodule generated by X). This is an upper bound for $\Gamma$ that is an element of $\Lambda$(*), so the conditions for applying Zorn's Lemma are fulfilled. Therefore, $\Gamma$ admits a $\subseteq$- maximal element.

For part b) The only things I know is that since $K$ is a field, then $M$ is a $K$-vector space, this fact will endow $M$ with a basis and every submodule (subspace in this case) will have a compliment, i.e. $\forall A\leq M:\exists A'\leq M$ such that $M=A \bigoplus A'$. From here I'm completly lost.

(*)The proof of this fact took me some lines, so for simplicity I didn't include it.

Thank you in advanced for any help provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (b) I would avoid using results like existence of bases, since
the exercise is related to the proof that bases exists.

You need to show that a maximal $N$ in $\Lambda$ is maximal.
Consider $M/N$. This vector space has dimension at least one, as $x\notin N$. If it has dimension one, then $N$ is maximal in $M$ (good!) otherwise
there is $y+N\in M/N$ linearly independent of $x+N$. Consider $N+Ky$...

Comment: So if $dim(M/N)>1$ there exists a nonzero class different from $x+N$, say $y+N$ which is linearly independent from $x+N$. Let us consider $K(y+N)=\left\{ky+N|k\in K\right\}$. Since $x+N$ and $y+N$ are l.i. then $x$ is not a ($K$)-multiple of $y$ then, $K(y+N)=N$ for $N$ being $\subseteq$-maximal. That would be a contradiction since we assumed $y+N$ was a nonzero class. I'm I getting it right?